# Spring Boot JPA - Join by two columns

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

**TL;DR : Help me join a table by two columns, one by fixed and another by variable value. It is @OneToOne.**

***Do this but in hibernate magic :***

```
SELECT t.*, c.*
FROM grid.app_users t
  JOIN app_dictionaries c on c.primary = 'USER_STATES' and c.secondary = t.state
;
```

---

I was trying to add another join column to my user entity (mapped to table `app_users`).

[image]

This column has to be filtered by `primary` (fixed *USER_STATES*) and `secondary`   (variable, in this case *A* or *P*) codes on `app_dictionaries` table.

[image]

Help me find a suitable join approach.

I could have just created a ***view*** and joined it by the above mentioned columns but that entails losing the ability to `insert` and `update` on `app_users`.

I am not very friendly with Hibernate and Spring JPA Repository.

**My User entity :**

```
package com.core.app.admin.entity;

import com.core.app.admin.auth.ValidPassword;
import com.core.app.admin.repository.RState;
import com.core.app.dicts.entity.EDict;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;
import lombok.Data;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.Set;

@Entity
@Table(name = "app_users")
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})
@Data
public class EUser {

  @Autowired
  RState repository;

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  @Column(name = "user_id")
  private int userId;
  @Column(name = "user_group_id")
  private int userGroupId;
  @Column(name = "name")
  private String name;
  @Column(name = "login")
  private String login;
  @ValidPassword
  @Column(name = "password")
  private String password;
  @Column(name = "state")
  private String state;
  @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  @JoinTable(
    name = "app_user_roles",
    joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"),
    inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id")
  )
  private Set<ERole> roles;
  @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "app_dictionaries")
  private EDict stateName = repository.getByPrimaryAndSecondary();

}
```

**My dictionary entity :**

```
package com.core.app.dicts.entity;

import lombok.Data;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.io.Serializable;

@Entity
@Table(
  name = "app_dictionaries",
  uniqueConstraints = {@UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"primary", "secondary"})}
)
@Data
public class EDict implements Serializable {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  @Column(name = "line_id")
  private int lineId;
  @Column(name = "primary")
  private String primary;
  @Column(name = "secondary")
  private String secondary;
  @Column(name = "name")
  private String name;
  @Column(name = "state")
  private String state;

}
```

**My state / dictionary repository :**

```
package com.core.app.admin.repository;

import com.core.app.dicts.entity.EDict;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import java.util.List;

@Repository
public interface RState extends JpaRepository<EDict, Integer> {

  List<EDict> findByPrimary(String primary);
  EDict getByPrimaryAndSecondary();

}
```

**My error :**

```
[org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator] while setting bean property 'entityManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#51933ecb': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Unknown mappedBy in: com.core.app.admin.entity.EUser.stateName, referenced property unknown: com.core.app.dicts.entity.EDict.app_dictionaries
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: i was trying something stupid and autowired a repository in my entity

Comment: Is it fixed ? You got what you wanted ?

Comment: nope, still messing with solutions on the web